# Why does this linked list Seg Fault?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

The following code results in a segmentation fault if insertBefore is called after insertAfter or if insertAfter is called multiple times.

```
void insertBefore(list *l, void *p){
    node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node) + l->SizeOfData);
    memcpy(newNode->item, p, l->SizeofData);
    l->curent->previous->next = newNode;
    l->current->previous = newNode;
}
void insertAfter(list *l, void *p){
    node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node) + l->SizeOfData);
    memcpy(newNode->item, p, l->SizeofData);
    l->curent->next->previous = newNode;
    l->current->previous->next = newNode;
    l->current = newNode;
}
```

The lists being used are:

```
struct node {
    struct node *previous;
    struct node *next;
    char item[];
};

typedef struct node node;

struct list {
    node *first;
    node *current;
    node *last;
    int SizeOfData;
};

list *newList(int b) {
    list *list = malloc(sizeof(list));
    node *sentnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    sentnode->previous = sentnode;
    sentnode->next = sentnode;
    list->first = sentnode;
    list->current = sentnode;
    list->last = sentnode;
    list->SizeOfData = b;
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Where does the debugger indicate is causing the seg fault?

Comment: I am using the C compiler so it doesn't specify where. Sorry.

Comment: Which os are you using and can you provide a minimal runnable example which exhibits the issue? A poor mans debugger is to just insert `printf` statements between the lines until you can see which one doesnt get printed

Comment: Turn warnings ON! `list *list = malloc(sizeof(list));`: Error, `list` undeclared!

Comment: `list *list = malloc(sizeof(list));` --> `struct list *list = malloc(sizeof(struct list));`

Comment: You should test all `malloc` return values before to dereference them...

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will now attempt to debug the insertAfter function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to set the `previous` and `next` pointers of `newNode`. There is also another bug in `insertAfter` (changed line).

```
void insertBefore(list *l, void *p){
    node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node) + l->SizeOfData);
    memcpy(newNode->item, p, l->SizeofData);
    newNode->previous = l->current->previous;   // Added line
    newNode->next = l->current;                 // Added line
    l->current->previous->next = newNode;
    l->current->previous = newNode;
}

void insertAfter(list *l, void *p){
    node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node) + l->SizeOfData);
    memcpy(newNode->item, p, l->SizeofData);
    newNode->previous = l->current;        // Added line
    newNode->next = l->current->next;      // Added line
    l->current->next->previous = newNode;  
    l->current->next = newNode;            // Changed line
    l->current = newNode;
}
```